# How can i config my CACHE_BACKEND

Tags: python, django

when i deal with session and page cache,i get a problem.
i use memcache to store my session info,
and i would like to use file to cache the site page.
The quesion is they both use CACHE_BACKEND,
if i make it like this: CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/',
then how can i make my page cache work with file?

Comment: Are you asking how you can have two separate cache backends: one for the session cache, and the other for the page cache?

Answer (score 1):

You have three possibilities:

0) use Beaker http://beaker.groovie.org/index.html

1) Do not use memcache for session storing but use the db session engine by adding 'django.contrib.sessions' to your INSTALLED_APPS (do not forget to syncdb to create the session tables). If you have concerns about performance you could use an in-memory table engine.

2) Implement your own session engine that use a separate cache:

SESSION_ENGINE='yourapp.session_engine'
SESSION_CACHE_BACKEND='memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'

then in session_engine.py something like (untested):

from django.contrib.sessions.backend.cache import SessionStore as BaseSessionStore
from django.core.cache import get_cache
from django.conf import settings

class SessionStore(BaseSessionStore):
  def **init**(self, session_key=None):
        super(SessionStore, self).**init**(session_key)
        self._cache = get_cache(settings.SESSION_CACHE_BACKEND)

Answer (score 0):

django 1.3 will be released soon and there will be support for multiple cache backends (look at the development docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/cache/).

You can use latest django svn checkout (it is not uncommon, django  svn is quite stable) or just wait a couple of weeks for a release.